# How to produce XML with attributes rather than nodes, using MvcContrib's XmlResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xml, xml-serialization, mvccontrib

I'm trying to generate an XML output from a type in C#. I'm Using the MvcContrib XmlResult class, which I've included a link to below.

As a simple test to see if I could get it working, I'm using the following code:

```
var topTen = new TopTen
{
    PerformanceTo = DateTime.Now,
    ShareClasses = new List<TopTenShareClass>()
                        {
                            new TopTenShareClass{Id = 1, Name = "a"},
                            new TopTenShareClass{Id = 2, Name = "b"},
                            new TopTenShareClass{Id = 3, Name = "c"}

                        }
};

return new XmlResult(topTen);
```

(with the 2 types defined as:)

```
public class TopTen
{
    public DateTime PerformanceTo { get; set; }
    public List<TopTenShareClass> ShareClasses { get; set; }
}

public class TopTenShareClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

to produce this output XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TopTen xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <PerformanceTo>2011-02-22T10:56:41.3094548+00:00</PerformanceTo>
  <ShareClasses>
    <TopTenShareClass>
      <Id>1</Id>
      <Name>a</Name>
    </TopTenShareClass>
    <TopTenShareClass>
      <Id>2</Id>
      <Name>b</Name>
    </TopTenShareClass>
    <TopTenShareClass>
      <Id>3</Id>
      <Name>c</Name>
    </TopTenShareClass>
  </ShareClasses>
</TopTen>
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to have the ID & Name tags appear as attributes in the `TopTenShareClass` node, rather than nodes themselves? Ideally the XML would be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TopTen xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <PerformanceTo>2011-02-22T10:56:41.3094548+00:00</PerformanceTo>
  <ShareClasses>
    <TopTenShareClass Id=1 Name='a'></TopTenShareClass>
    <TopTenShareClass Id=2 Name='b'></TopTenShareClass>
    <TopTenShareClass Id=3 Name='c'></TopTenShareClass>
  </ShareClasses>
</TopTen>
```

For reference, the XmlResult definition is available here: http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/5f542a2e51e9#src%2fMVCContrib%2fActionResults%2fXmlResult.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could control the XML serialization process [using attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z.aspx):

```
public class TopTenShareClass
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess it just uses `XmlSerializer` for the implementation, so:

```
public class TopTenShareClass
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

A full list is on MSDN: [Attributes That Control XML Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Re your example, I would actually expect:

```
<TopTenShareClass Id="1" Name="a"/>
<TopTenShareClass Id="2" Name="b"/>
<TopTenShareClass Id="3" Name="c"/>
```