# How to add an attribute to an XML node when that node is serialised from a List?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, mvccontrib

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077308/how-to-produce-xml-with-attributes-rather-than-nodes-using-mvccontribs-xmlresul) yesterday, wondering how to produce XML with attributes using MVCContrib. The answer was to use `[XmlAttribute]`.

Since, I've successfully used `[XmlAttribute]` to get the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TopTen xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <SectorName>Property - Direct UK</SectorName>
  <PerformanceTo>2011-01-31T00:00:00</PerformanceTo>
  <OrderedShareClassReturns>
    <OrderedShareClassReturn Name="Property L" Performance="11.074980" />
    <OrderedShareClassReturn Name="UK Property Trust I Inc" Performance="10.512610" />
    <OrderedShareClassReturn Name="UK Property Trust I Acc" Performance="10.466310" />
    <OrderedShareClassReturn Name="UK Property Trust R Inc" Performance="9.725650" />
  </OrderedShareClassReturns>
</TopTen>
```

Now I need to add a second `<ShareClassReturns>` node to the XML, and I'd like to add an attribute to that element, so the XML becomes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TopTen xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <SectorName>Property - Direct UK</SectorName>
  <PerformanceTo>2011-01-31T00:00:00</PerformanceTo>
  <OrderedShareClassReturns order="top"> // how can I add the "top" & "bottom" attributes?
    <OrderedShareClassReturn Name="Property L" Performance="11.074980" />
    <OrderedShareClassReturn Name="UK Property Trust I Inc" Performance="10.512610" />
    <OrderedShareClassReturn Name="UK Property Trust I Acc" Performance="10.466310" />
    <OrderedShareClassReturn Name="UK Property Trust R Inc" Performance="9.725650" />
  </OrderedShareClassReturnss>
  <OrderedShareClassReturns order="bottom">
    <OrderedShareClassReturn Name="Property L" Performance="0.074980" />
    <OrderedShareClassReturn Name="UK Property Trust I Inc" Performance="1.512610" />
    <OrderedShareClassReturn Name="UK Property Trust I Acc" Performance="2.466310" />
    <OrderedShareClassReturn Name="UK Property Trust R Inc" Performance="3.725650" />
  </OrderedShareClassReturns>
</TopTen>
```

But I don't know how to do this. The objects that I'm serializing are defined as:

```
public class TopTen
{

    public string SectorName { get; set; }
    public DateTime PerformanceTo { get; set; }

    public List<OrderedShareClassReturn> OrderedShareClassReturns { get; set; }
}

public class OrderedShareClassReturn
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public decimal Performance { get; set; }
}
```

So the question is, how can I add that attribute to the `<OrderedShareClassReturns>` element? Do I need to define a `OrderedShareClassReturns` as a class that implements a `List<OrderedShareClassReturn>`, and have a property called `order`, which has `[XmlAttribute]`? Or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that you'd need to add another class:

```
public class ReturnsWrapper {

    [XmlElement("OrderedShareClassReturn")]
    public List<OrderedShareClassReturn> Items { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("order")]
    public string Order {get;set;}
}
```

and have:

```
public class TopTen
{

    public string SectorName { get; set; }
    public DateTime PerformanceTo { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("OrderedShareClassReturns")]
    public List<ReturnsWrapper> Returns { get; set; }
}
```